# How can I put a moving square into a PDF-document using tikz-, animate-package (and arara?)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate, arara

How can I produce something like that

[image]

into a PDF using TikZ? (Note: It does not need colors or shadows, a simple square would be fine)

I remember there was an arara-methode, which produces the single pics for the animated gif.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% #arara:  I DON'T KNOW

\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]

%I DON'T KNOW
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is "this" an animated gif? If so, that has nothing to do with arara, just have a look at the `animate` and `media9` packages, as despicted at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5396/34551.

Comment: Yes, in fact, an animated gif. I thought, I have to produce the single pictures for the gif-file  using a (or two?) arara-rules. But it is long time ago, I read about. I do not remenber the names.

Comment: I edited a better desciption...

Comment: Gif are not convenient *at all*, you should convert your file to an other format. Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74073/34551 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7602/34551

Comment: I do not want to use the shown file. I would like to produce that with latex / arara

Comment: And what are your sources files? Image, video, flash animation?

Comment: TikZ is not good at central perspective 3D projection drawing. Have a look at `pst-solides3d` package.